# Disable Export to Spreadsheet in SharePoint Custom List

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

Is it possible to disable (or remove) the option in a custom list to export to Excel?  We have a sensitive list on a team site with a large number of items and views whereby the business sponsor would like people to be able to see the data but not have the ability to pull down into Excel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [define a custom permission level](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263239.aspx). The easiest way is to copy from one of the default ones.

Once you create your permission level uncheck the following option:

```
[] Use Client Integration Features
```

Create a group that has this permission level, and and your users to this group.

Answer (score 3):

+1 to Toni for the technical answer (and to you for the question). I find the reasoning concerning, though: "the business sponsor would like people to be able to see the data but not have the ability to pull down into Excel". Disabling the export just makes it more difficult, in the "select with the mouse, copy, paste into Excel" vein of difficult. I suppose it's possible the sponsor doesn't know that it's that simple even with the export option disabled? Granted, I know nothing about the list or the whys behind it, but if it's genuinely sensitive, the storage, care, and usage of the information in the list probably needs to be discussed further (?). Disabling export is likely to just give your sponsor a false sense of security.

Answer (score 1):

I found this very useful.

I am using a custom form that filters the view to show items created by [ME] or to show all records when approver is [ME].  That's almost what I want - I actually want to check for membership of a group and show all if they are in it.  What this allows is the creation of a leave or expenses app without writing a single scrap of code!

What I've found:
1. Create a custom list, modify the form in Info Path Designer 2010
2. Create a custom permission from View Only, add the right to add items to lists and remove remote interfaces and client integration - disables their ability to create personal views, exporting to excel and access or other more advanced means of obtaining list data
3. Customise the view and filter it by specific users
4. Create a custom workflow in SharePoint 2010

Then you have an app that has security and can be used for something like expense approval and have not written any code!

...Now I just have to work out step 3 such that you can give all users of a particular group access to all records in the list.  I guess MS didn't think of that, at the moment I can only make it show approval requests sent to you, which means if you want to have someone overseeing it they would have to create their own personal view to see all.